# Why are there two instances of `Promise.all` necessary in http request fetch and response?

Tags: javascript, promise

In the code below, we're trying to fetch several urls, and handle errors when responses come back.

I notice the use of 2 `Promise.all` here. Why is it necessary to use the second `Promise.all`? What will happen when you remove it?

```
Promise.all( //1st one
    urls.map(url => fetch(url).catch(err => err))
  )
  .then(responses => Promise.all( //2nd one
    // if it's an error then pass on
    // otherwise response.json() and catch errors as results
    responses.map(r => r instanceof Error ? r : r.json().catch(err => err))
  ))
  .then(results => {
    alert(results[0].name); // Ilya Kantor
    alert(results[1]); // SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    alert(results[2]); // TypeError: failed to fetch (text may vary)
  });
```

Comment: Because you have an array of promises, not a single promise.

Comment: @tkausl The first one already takes care of handling this, why is the second one necessary?

Comment: because `responses` is an array of promises

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second `Promise.all()` maps all the successful responses to JSON.

Because [`Response.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) itself returns a promise, the resulting array from `responses.map(...)` might look something like

```js
[ error, Promise<Object>, Promise<Object>, error, Promise<Object> ]
```

In order to wait for all the `json()` promises to resolve, you need to use a second `Promise.all()`.

The non-promises in the array will be treated as `Promise.resolve(item)`

---

Note that this code could be written much more succinctly (see other answers). This answer is more of a *"why is the code the way it is"*

Answer (score 2):

You can just combine fetch and json in a single chain:

```js
urls = [
    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1",
    "http://wtf"
]

Promise.all(
    urls.map(url => 
        fetch(url).then(r => r.json()).catch(String))
).then(console.log)
```